# Using the Google Maps Chart in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a set of Buoy data. These buoys are located in various ocean locations. I understand a source file for Data Studio can be used by the Google Maps chart with city or states, countries, etc. What I'm looking to do is map the various buoys by there actual geo code (lat/long) and then click on one to bring up the details. Can this be done? I can put the data in any format but can't figure out the lat/long part to properly display it.

Answer (score 0):

The glaring mistake I made to this problem was not setting the fields in the google sheets to the correct type e.g. GEO. So the field where I have lat/long, instead of text, set to GEO then Lat/Long. All will now work. Any Geo (city, state, etc.) has to be set as such when you bring the file, sheets in my case, into the report.